# SAML is not honouring Token Lifetime

Tags: authentication, saml-2.0, adfs2.0, service-provider, idp

**ADFS 2.0 Token Lifetime is not honouring**

I have configured SAML authentication using ADFS 2.0 as IDP. please find the config details below,

**Config 1:**
**WebSSOLifetime = 60
RP's Token lifetime = 80**

if try to login after 65 minutes, it's asking me to re-authenticate

**Config 2:
WebSSOLifetime = 60
RP's Token lifetime = 30**

if I try to login after 30 minutes, I can able to login without re-autheticate.

As per my analysis, SSO is working based on WebSSOLifetime. what role RP's Token Lifetime is playing here

Answer (score 0):

Consider the WebSSOLifetime to correspond to a refresh token, and the RP token to correspond to an access token.

When a user logs in to your application, the user presents the RP token to the application. If the RP token is expired, the user goes to ADFS to get a new RP token.
ADFS will check their "WebSSOLifetime" token, and if the "WebSSOLifetime" is still valid, a new RP token will be issued, otherwise the user will have to authenticate to ADFS again and in turn get a new "WebSSOLifetime" token and RP token

This is very similar to how Kerberos works

Comment: I am also thinking in that way but how to verify that. is there any option available to track RP tokens?